# Trying to import my css file in react but it doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'm creating an app in react. Having webpack installed I'm trying to add some styling but it doesn't seem to work.

My app.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import IndecisionApp from './components/IndecisionApp'
import './styles/styles.css'

ReactDOM.render(<IndecisionApp />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

My webpack.config

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}
```

style.css file

```
* {
  color: red;
}
```

app.js and styles folder are in the same folder. Shouldn't this work?

Btw, I'm not getting any errors or anything.

EDIT

Error in terminal (new edit: fixed this error, but initial problem still not solved)

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/styles.css
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Jossif\Desktop\Projects\react-course-projects\indecision-app\r-08-04-refactor\src\styles\styles.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| * {
|   color: red;
| }
 @ ./src/app.js 15:0-30
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 ./src/app.js
```

My webpack.config file

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  }
}
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "indecision-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Andrew Mead",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-modal": "2.2.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: show your app.js code

Comment: update above with the whole app.js file

Comment: what you are doing inside IndecisionApp ? i mean you want to apply default color to be red from your IndecisionApp component right ??

Comment: It's a udemy course I'm following. Inside IndecisionApp I have a couple of function components to set the state based on what's clicked or called. The css works in his video (posted the question there as well)

Comment: Your webpack.config is correct, but make sure you've actually installed style-loader and css-loader. Check your package.json file. If you don't find it listed under dependencies, you need to install it for css to work.

Comment: They are listed. I updated the code above with an error I'm now getting in the terminal

Comment: could you upload your webpack.config and your package.json

Comment: Sure, uploaded them both above

Comment: I copied you webpack.config, it works well for me. Try an npm run build, then start your app again.

Comment: I rerun the webpack config and live server and it works now!